# Nested UpdatePanel and ModalPopupExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one asp.net page that has one complex web-control that theControl.

theControls contains `UpdatePanel` with Conditional mode `UpdateMode="Conditional"` of update and a PopupModelExtender to displayed as modal.
The parent update panel `UpdateMode="Always"`.

All things looks good. **but when I save rendered page in the client-side via Fire-Fox, the original page-size increases per number of postback!**

I found that below lines added to my page dynamically too:

```
 Sys.Application.add_init(function() {    
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior, {"BackgroundCssClass":"DlgModalBG","PopupControlID":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_main_EditorCtrl1_btnSave_dlgPanel","dynamicServicePath":"/Composer.aspx","id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_main_EditorCtrl1_btnSave_dlg_ModalPopupExtender"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_main_EditorCtrl1_btnSave_btnSave"));    
});
```

**exactly for each post-back increase this block**

```
 Sys.Application.add_init(function() {   
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior, {"BackgroundCssClass":"DlgModalBG","PopupControlID":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_main_EditorCtrl1_Page0_RemovePageButton1_RemPagePanel","dynamicServicePath":"/Composer.aspx","id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_main_EditorCtrl1_Page0_RemovePageButton1_RemovePage_ModalPopupExtender"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_main_EditorCtrl1_Page0_RemovePageButton1_Button_RemovePage"));    
 });
```

What is the problem? Why the above lines will not removed, if added.

I'm really bored!, Please help me.